# console service response inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

i have written a service with take parameter on the basis of which it response me with the response of http request.

```
    this.getPaymentDueDetails=function(date){
    this.getfromRemote('paymentdue/'+btoa(date))
    .success(function(response){
        return response;
    })
    .error(function(response){
        return false;
    })
}
```

`getfromRemote` is my another service which make `http` request

now i am trying to get the response of this service call inside my controller function

```
 $scope.callDueReports=function(blockNum){
       var data;
       data=myAngService.getPaymentDueDetails('2015-04-20');
console.log(data);
        }
```

its quite obvious that i wont get any thing in data as the page loads initially but i want the result of getPaymentDueDetails int it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify your service to return the promise like below.

```
this.getPaymentDueDetails = function(date) {
    return this.getfromRemote('paymentdue/' + btoa(date));
};
```

And in controller check if the promise is resolved.

```
$scope.callDueReports = function(blockNum) {
    var data;

    myAngService.getPaymentDueDetails('2015-04-20').then(function(dataFromService) {
            data = dataFromService;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(response) {
            console.error('error');
        });
};
```